# Gingerbread - No Support for Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS

Tags: android

When I send user to settings on Ginger bread device, I get error that there is no activity to handle the intent Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS

What's the solution. How can I send user to Development settings?  How can I let them adjust this.

Comment: Try `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get error that there is no activity to handle the intent Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS

Not every device, prior to API Level 15, had to support this action.

> What's the solution

Do not support Android 2.x, by setting your `minSdkVersion` to 15.

Or, let the user know that you cannot take them straight to this screen, and just lead the user over to the general Settings app, via `Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS`.

Comment: Ok, do you think for a significant number of these 2.3 devices there is api way to turn off usb. I know it does not work on newer devices ....

Comment: @MuayThai: Sorry, but I do not know what "turn off usb" means, let alone what it has to do with `ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS`.